# Submit form on button click with FETCH and send an email with PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, fetch, phpmailer

I want to send a form on button click with fetch API to index.php where i validate the form. If there were no errors in the form I want to send an email with PHPMailer to the client. For some reason the client does not receive the e-mail.
I have searched for hours for an answer but I couldn't solve the problem.

Here is the javascript code:

```
 const form = document.querySelector("#myForm");
      form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        const formData = new FormData(form);
        fetch("index.php", {
          method: 'post',
          body: formData
        }).then((resp) => resp.json())
        .then(function (text) {
          console.log(text); //Do something with the response, which is an array
          if(text !== undefined && text.length > 0) { //The array isn't empty
            //Show errors
            const formdiverror = document.querySelector(".col-100-form-error");
            const colform = document.querySelector(".col-100-form"); //showing error
            colform.style.display = "block";
            formdiverror.innerHTML = "";
            text.forEach(t => formdiverror.innerHTML += t + "</br>");
          } else {
            //array is empty, no errors
             const colform = document.querySelector(".col-100-form");
             if(colform !== null || colform !== undefined) colform.style.display = "none";
             alert("You succesfully bought the product!");
            //window.location.replace("index.html"); //if there was no error redirect to index.html
          }
        });
      })
```

The php:

```
<?php
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;
require 'Exception.php';
require 'PHPMailer.php';
require 'SMTP.php';
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require "class.phpmailer.php";
require "class.smtp.php";


$errors = [];

if(isset($_POST["name"])) {
   
     /*I took out the validation to simplify the code*/
    if (!empty($errors)) {
        echo json_encode($errors);
    } else {
        echo json_encode([]);
        $mail = new PHPMailer();
        $mail->isSMTP();
        $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
        $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
        $mail->Username = "mymail@gmail.com"; //paste one generated by Mailtrap
        $mail->Password = 'mypasswd'; 
        $mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls'; // secure transfer enabled REQUIRED for GMail
        $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->addAddress("customer@gmail.com", 'First Last');
        $mail->addReplyTo('mymail@gmail.com', 'First Last');
        $mail->setFrom('mymail@gmail.com', 'John Doe');
        $mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
        $mail->isHTML(true);
        $mailContent = "<h1>Send HTML Email using SMTP in PHP</h1>
        <p>This is a test email I’m sending using SMTP mail server with PHPMailer.</p>";
         $mail->Body = $mailContent;
         $mail->send();
        //If I try this way it gives an errror: Unexpected token in JSON at position 
        /* if($mail->send()){
            echo ('Message has been sent');
        }else{
            echo ('Message could not be sent.');
            echo ('Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo);
        }*/
    }
} 
?>
```

I don't get any errors so I don't know where the problem is.
I have disabled the two way verification, and I gave access to less secure apps.

Comment: Try adding $mail->SMTPDebug = 2; in your PHP file
 and check for the logs. It will give a fair idea of the issue.

Comment: why this line? `echo json_encode([]);` ? That would definitely explain the error `If I try this way it gives an errror: Unexpected token in JSON at position...`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius I use the echo json_encode([]); so that i know on the client side that i don't have any errors in the form validation.

Comment: If you output content BEFORE sending headers you will often get errors and as the Fetch function is expecting json the response from PHP should be json rather than plain text as you do above.. otherwise change `(resp) => resp.json()` for `(resp) => resp.text()`

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsius If I use resp.json(), then I need to use echo json_encode() every time in php? I send and array to the client side, which contains the errors of the validation (strings). If i use resp.text() and I console.log()-it, it only prints "array".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, you are importing **both** versions 5 and 6 of PHPMailer! That's not going to go well; go with 6. Delete these lines and the files they point to; you don't need them:

```php
require 'PHPMailerAutoload.php';
require "class.phpmailer.php";
require "class.smtp.php";
```

If you're confused about how to import libraries in general, now would be a very good time to learn about [composer](https://getcomposer.org).

Oddly enough, when you comment out code that shows you where the error is, it no longer shows you when there's an error... that `console.log(text);` line should show you what your browser sees too.

The best way to approach this is to debug one thing at a time.

First make sure that your form is actually delivering the data to your script in the format that it should be – given the JSON error (which is not from PHPMailer), it seems very likely that this is *not* the case, and that's probably the source of all your problems. So add this near the top of your script:

```
var_dump($_REQUEST);
```

This will break your ajax request (because the output is not JSON), but you will be able to see the raw response in your browser's web inspector.

Once you've confirmed that it's in the correct format and contains all your expected form data, remove that `var_dump` line and move on to checking that you are accessing the properties within the JSON correctly. Again, you may find it best to show this in your browser's inspector. Once you're sure you're extracting all the bits of data you want in the right way, moving on to sending an email.

Given the *very* common problems with using gmail via SMTP, it's a good idea to test your email code with fixed values, separately from your ajax stuff – it's hard enough to debug by itself without other stuff getting in the way.

Now you've got to the point where all the individual pieces work, join them back together and check each step as you do so.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. I tried to execute only the  mail function without any ajax, and it turned out i had some kind of problem with gmail. I had to re-log to the account and it somehow solved the problem.

Comment: Yes, gmail does that. This is covered in the PHPMailer troubleshooting guide, but you need to be able to see it happening to know to look for it, and that’s a bit harder to do with Ajax than a traditional page load. Glad you worked it out.

Comment: I have one more question. The mailing works, but it take an unusual long time for the fetch response to arrive. Sometimes it is pending for 1-2s but sometimes even for like 7-8secs. Do you have a clue what is causing the problem?

Comment: Yes, email, and especially SMTP to remote servers can be very slow, often deliberately so. It's really not suited to synchronous sending during page/request processing, though that doesn't stop many people trying to do it. The best way to speed this up is to decouple your sending request from the SMTP process, and the easiest way to do that is to relay your messages through a local mail server. This will reduce your send time (as seen from your script) to a fraction of a second.

Comment: I see. Thank you very much for the help!